# How do I use a toolbar in AngularDart?

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2, angular-dart

I just found out about AngularDart today and I want to build a sample app but I got stuck.

I'm currently browsing https://material-components-web.appspot.com/toolbar/index.html and I'd like to use the **Waterfall Flexible Toolbar** for my dart web app.

I'm using this website in order to reference the angular components for Dart https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components_example but I can't find any toolbar examples.

Does that mean that I have to build my own toolbar? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently in this case it's called Application Layout https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/tree/master/lib/app_layout